# Simplifying Excel Forumulas

Tags: excel

I suspect there is a better way to write this formula:

```
=IF('Table Values'!C2='Table Values'!B12,'Table Values'!E12,IF('Table Values'!C2='Table Values'!B13,'Table Values'!E13,IF('Table Values'!C2='Table Values'!B14,'Table Values'!E14,IF('Table Values'!C2='Table Values'!B15,'Table Values'!E15,IF('Table Values'!C2='Table Values'!B16,'Table Values'!E16,IF('Table Values'!C2='Table Values'!B17,'Table Values'!E17,IF('Table Values'!C2='Table Values'!B18,'Table Values'!E18,IF('Table Values'!C2='Table Values'!B19,'Table Values'!E19))))))))
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that If formula? It can likely be reduced down...but if you have an example of some data and the formula, and expected results, it would help!

Comment: 1) avoid calling this a forum we don't like that because we are a Question and Answer site. 2) meta.stackoverlow.com for specifically dealing with stackoverflow or meta.stackexchange.com for dealing with all sites as a whole. 3) `INDEX(E12:E19,MATCH(C2,B12:B19,0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,B12:E19,4,false)
```

Which means look for c2, in the range b12:e19, return the 4th column of that same range (E), and (the false means) do an exact match against the leftmost column (in this case B).

Comment: This worked. And the details of 'why' it works helps teach me HOW to use it in the future.